What does analytic uniformly in $s$ mean?
Suppose I have a complex vector space $V$ with finite basis $\{e_{1},...,e_{s}\}$. Then, I can consider the algebra $\mathcal{U}$ of formal polynomials on the variables $e_{1},...,e_{s}$. Suppose further that we introduced a norm on $\mathcal{U}$, say, $\|\cdot\|_{\mathcal{U}}$, in such a way that $\mathcal{U}$ becomes a normed algebra. In the following, it may be useful to consider Banach spaces, so we may also take the completion of $\mathcal{U}$ with respect to its norm, which I will denote by the same symbols.
Generally speaking, a function $f$ between complex Banach spaces is said to be analytic in open set $U$ if for every $x_{0} \in U$ the limit:
$$f'(x_{0}) = \lim_{x\to x_{0}} \frac{f(x)-f(x_{0})}{x-x_{0}}$$
exists in the norm sense.
Now, back to our Banach space $\mathcal{U}$, suppose $f$ is a function defined on $\mathcal{U}$ and taking values on (possibly another) complex Banach space. Consider the following statement.

The function $f$ is analytic in $x$ for every $x \in U \subset \mathcal{U}$ and analyticity holds uniformly in $s$.

I am confused with the precise meaning of this statement. What does "analytic uniformly in $s$" means? It seems to be using another definition of analyticity, e.g. by Taylor expansion of $f$, but even in this case I don't understand what it would mean to be analytic uniformly in $s$.

How do you divide on a vector in a Banach space in your definition of analyticity?

Where did you encounter this statement?
